# AdonisJs: Why is the migration marking a syntax error near the unsigned, when other migration have the same syntax and works perfectly?

Tags: javascript, mysql, migration, adonis.js

I'm trying to run some migrations for a database about a car shop, and currently 5 out of 7 migration run without any kind of error, however, by the time it reaches the sixth migration an 'ER_PARSE_ERROR' happens when the table is trying to assign a foreign key to the parent table. 
In this case, the table 'hoja_de_partes' has a column named 'idMECANICO' and the 6th table called 'repuestos' is assigning a foreign key to the column in the parent table, but when the run is in process it crashes around this table and it marks a syntax error near the 'unsigned' in line 1. I don't know what could be making such error because in the previous migration I do the exact same thing and nothing out of the ordinary happens.

> This is the parent table

```
'use strict'

/** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Schema')} */
const Schema = use('Schema')

class HojaDeParteSchema extends Schema {
    up() {
        this.create('hoja_de_partes', (table) => {
            table.string('idHOJA', 45).primary()
            table.string('CONCEPTO', 45).notNullable()
            table.integer('CANTIDAD', 11).notNullable()
            table.string('REPARACION', 45).notNullable()              
            table.integer('idMECANICO',
            11).unsigned().references('idMEC').inTable('mecanico_responsables')
            table.timestamps()
           })
        }

   down() {
       this.drop('hoja_de_partes')
   }
}
module.exports = HojaDeParteSchema
```

> This is the child table

```
'use strict'

 /** @type {import('@adonisjs/lucid/src/Schema')} */
 const Schema = use('Schema')

 class RepuestoSchema extends Schema {
    up() {
        this.create('repuestos', (table) => {
             table.increments('idREP', 11).primary()
             table.string('DESCRIPCION', 45).notNullable()
             table.integer('COSTOUNIT', 11).notNullable()
             table.integer('PRECIOUNIT', 11).notNullable()
             table.integer('IMP_PARCIAL', 11).notNullable()
             table.string('idHOJADEPARTE', 
             45).unsigned().references('idHOJA').inTable('hoja_de_partes')
             table.integer('idMECANICODEPARTE', 
             11).unsigned().references('idMECANICO').inTable('hoja_de_partes')
             table.timestamps()
         })
     }

     down() {
         this.drop('repuestos')
    }
 }

module.exports = RepuestoSchema
```

> THIS...is the error the terminal is marking, like I said, I don't know what is making this error

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlMessage:
   'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
    version for the right syntax to use near \'unsigned, `idMECANICODEPARTE` int(11) unsigned, 
    `created_at` datetime, `updated_\' at line 1',
    sqlState: '42000',
    index: 0,
    sql:
        'create table `repuestos` (`idREP` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
        `DESCRIPCION` varchar(45) not null, `COSTOUNIT` int(11) not null, `PRECIOUNIT` int(11) not 
         null, `IMP_PARCIAL` int(11) not null, `idHOJADEPARTE` varchar(45) unsigned, 
        `idMECANICODEPARTE` int(11) unsigned, `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime)' }
```

The previous migrations have the same .unsigned().references('column') in their sytax and all 5 run without problems, event the parent table 'hoja_de_partes' has a foreign key assigned to him and i didnt pop out an error of any kind.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated, also sorry if my indentation is poorly I'm trying to work my way around the length of some of these tables.

Answer (score 2):

There is no unsigned `varchar`, use `INT` instead. Then remove length on your `INT` columns, no point adding since its always `4 bytes`.

```
create table `repuestos` 
(`idREP` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key
 , `DESCRIPCION` varchar(45) not null
 , `COSTOUNIT` int not null
 , `PRECIOUNIT` int not null
 , `IMP_PARCIAL` int not null
 , `idHOJADEPARTE` int unsigned
 , `idMECANICODEPARTE` int unsigned
 , `created_at` datetime
 , `updated_at` datetime)
```

Comment: thank you so much! I didn't think it could be something so silly!

Answer (score 0):

unsigned syntax like this.

```
table.integer('idHOJADEPARTE').unsigned().references('idHOJA').inTable('hoja_de_partes')
```

a string is not allowed because integer as unsigned more info view [knex](https://knexjs.org/#Schema-unsigned) documents

after this changes it's work